# Ajuda com erro Método não-estático requer um destino ao criar arquivo txt

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um código em C# que cria um arquivo txt e depois baixa o mesmo.

O código funciona muito bem em minha máquina local, mas ao upá-lo pro servidor, dá um erro:

> Método não-estático requer um destino.

```
public ActionResult GeraBpa()
    {
        var caminho = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content");
        int linhaTexto = 1;
        int linhaItem = 1;
        Int64 digito = 0;
        string cmp = Request.QueryString["cmp"];
        oUsuario = (usuario)Session["usuario"];
        sm oSMS = modelOff.sms.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ibge == oUsuario.ibge);

        //cria o arquivo txt
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter($"{caminho}/PA" + oUsuario.ibge + cmp + ".txt")) 
        {
            //cria uma lista com as informacoes que eu preciso
            List<bpac> bpa = modelOff.bpacs.Where(p => p.cmp == cmp && p.ibge == oUsuario.ibge).ToList(); 
            //preenche o arquivo txt com os dados da lista criada acima
            foreach (bpac linha in bpa) 
            {
                file.WriteLine(
                "02" +
                linha.cnes +
                linha.cmp +//competencia
                linha.cbo +
                string.Format("{0:000}", linhaTexto) + 
                string.Format("{0:00}", linhaItem) +
                linha.pa +
                "000" +
                string.Format("{0:000000}", linha.quant) +
                "EXT"
                );

                digito += Convert.ToInt64(linha.pa);
                digito += linha.quant;
                linhaItem++;
                if (linhaItem > 99)
                {
                    linhaItem = 1;
                    linhaTexto++;
                }
            }

            linhaTexto++;
            linhaItem = 1;

        digito = digito % 1111;
        digito += 1111;

        //pega todas as linhas criadas anteriormente e salva em uma lista
        List<string> linhas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines($"{caminho}/PA" + oUsuario.ibge + cmp + ".txt").ToList();
        //cria uma nova linha
        string primeiraLinha = "01#BPA#" +
                cmp + //competencia
                linhas.Count.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0') + //total de linhas
                linhaTexto.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0') + //total de folhas
                digito.ToString() +
                oSMS.responsavel.PadRight(30, ' ') +
                oSMS.sigla.PadRight(6, ' ') +
                oSMS.cnpj.PadRight(14, ' ') +
                "SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE SAUDE           M          " +
                "";

        //insere a primeira linha no topo das outras
        linhas.Insert(0, primeiraLinha);
        //salva novamente o arquivo
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines($"{caminho}/PA" + oUsuario.ibge + cmp + ".txt", linhas);

        //disponibiliza o arquivo para download
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{caminho}/PA" + oUsuario.ibge + cmp + ".txt");
        string fileName = "PA" + oUsuario.ibge + cmp + ".txt";
        return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

Não consegui um erro mais específico, visto que o erro só dá no servidor online e não na minha máquina.

Espero que consigam me ajudar.

**EDITADO**

Alterei as permissões (botei acesso 100% pra todos os usuários), mas recebi erro de acesso:

> O acesso ao caminho 'F:\Inetpub\vhosts\italorodrigo.com.br\bpa.italorodrigo.com.br\Content\PA260500201708.txt'

Detalhe é que o arquivo não foi criado

Comment: Não tem a linha? Se não tiver, vai isolando pra ficar mais fácil saber onde é o erro. Pode ser em vários lugares.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta. deu erro de acesso. mas já fiz a permissão

Comment: consegui resolver. tinha que dar acesso ao grupo de pool

Comment: se alguem que entenda disso possa explicar melhor o que significa é bom